# Widget not rebuilding after changeNotifier called

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I have a provider with an int variable `currentPage` that defines the initial page of a PageView. I have this because I want to change the currentPage with widgets that far under the tree, or descendent widgets. I've set up everything correctly, but when changeNotifier is called, the page doesn't change.

Here's the provider class-

```
class CurrentPageProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  int? currentPage;
  CurrentPageProvider({this.currentPage});

  changeCurrentPage(int page) {
    currentPage = page;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

To use it, I've wrapped my MaterialWidget with a MultiProvider as such-

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => CurrentPageProvider(currentPage: 0))
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "Test",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primaryColor: yellowColor,
        ),
        home: const ResponsiveRoot(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the widget where the child should rebuild, but isn't-

```
class ResponsiveRoot extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResponsiveRoot({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int currentPage = Provider.of<CurrentPageProvider>(context).currentPage!;
    print("CurrentPageUpdated");
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: ((context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth > kWebScreenWidth) {
          return const WebscreenLayout();
        } else {    //The page view is here
          return MobileScreenLayout(     
            currentPage: currentPage,
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Upon debugging, I've found out that "CurrentPageUdated" gets printed when I'm calling the `changeCurrentPage`. However, the initState of the `MobileScreenLayout` doesn't get called (This widget has the pageView)

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `WebscreenLayout` is built, but only `MobileScreenLayout` is not built?

Comment: No, currently The kWebScreenWidth is 1000, so the webscreenlayout doesn't get build at all (This is intentional). The problem is that the MobileScreenLayout doesn't get *rebuilt* when currentPage is changed and changeNotifier is called

Comment: Could you show me the code where `changeCurrentPage` is called?

Answer (score 2):

in order to update the state of the the app you need to use Consumer widget.

```
Consumer<Your_provider_class>(
    builder: (BuildContext context, provider_instance, widget?){
                
                  },
    child: any_widget, but not neccessary,
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that even though your `Provider.of` mechanism needs to listen to changes, it does not.

What you can do is, do the recommended way on the documentation and you can either use the `watch` extension function or use `Consumer` or `Selector` widgets.

Here is an example on how to do it with your example with a Selector.

For more information read about Selector [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html)

```
class ResponsiveRoot extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResponsiveRoot({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Selector<CurrentPageProvider, int>(
      selector: (context, provider) => provider.currentPage!,
      builder: (context, currentPage, child) {
        print("CurrentPageUpdated");

        return LayoutBuilder(
          builder: ((context, constraints) {
            if (constraints.maxWidth > kWebScreenWidth) {
              return const WebscreenLayout();
            } else {
              //The page view is here
              return MobileScreenLayout(
                currentPage: currentPage,
              );
            }
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. [`Provider.of`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider/of.html) *does* listen to changes by default, and triggers a rebuild.

Comment: So what do you suspect is going on here? :(